# Angular form requires submit twice before scope var shows

Tags: html, angularjs

Based on the firebase sample to reset a user's password:

```
reset: function (email) {
      var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
      ref.resetPassword({
         email: email
      }, function (error) {
         if(error) {
            $rootScope.message = '';

            switch(error.code) {
            case "INVALID_USER":
               $rootScope.error = "The specified user account does not exist.";
               break;
            default:
               $rootScope.error = "Error resetting password:" + error;
            }
         } else {
            $rootScope.error = '';
            $rootScope.message = "Thank you, you should receive an email containing your new password."
         }
      });
```

The html page contains the following:

```
<p ng-show="message">{{message}}</p>
<p ng-show="error">{{error}}</p>
```

Curiously, even if reset method is executed, the messages will only appear after being called twice?

I tried wrapping the if / else of the resetPassword callback in a `$rootScope.apply()` method, but changed nothing.

What am I missing?

Comment: you haven't shown enough of the HTML to understand why this might happen, but it is most likely related to the usage of `$rootScope`.  `error` and `message` are primitive types, not objects, and if the *actual* `$scope` has `error` or `message` defined, they will hide the properties on `$rootScope`, due to JavaScript Prototype inheritance.  Using `$rootScope` at all is a code smell.

Comment: add $rootScope.$apply() or $rootScope.$digest() after you set properties.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Nishi's comment, by adding $rootScope.$apply() at the end of the reset callback method, it worked.